# Issue with importing .csv using MS Jet OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oledb

I'm importing a CSV file to SQL for an ASP .NET application. I am able to import the .csv, however one column contains null values if there is anything other than numbers in it.

This row imports fine:

```
1109,003,IN,0093219095,3/17/2013,3/21/2013,,Sobeys Warehouse,4819.13,61.37,4880.50,RV,1109-003
```

The fourth column is NULL in SQL:

```
1109,999,IN,REF 44308/S. DRA,3/18/2013,3/21/2013,,"EC Rebates W/E -02 14, 2013",-200.02,0.00,-200.02,SA,1109-999
```

All other columns that have text in them import fine, just the fourth one is an issue. I can't figure out what could possibly be different about the affected column over the others. If I replace the text with numbers it imports so its something to do with text data.  SQL field is nvarchar(50) so its not a datatype issue.

My connection string (**dir** contains the path to the folder):

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" + dir + "\\\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';";
```

Import code:

```
    public DataTable GetCSV(string path)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            return null;
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        string file = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"" + dir + "\\\";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';";
        string query = "SELECT * FROM " + file;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);

        try
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
        }

        da.Dispose();

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to see the data in the `OleDbDataAdapter`? Also you should not be swallowing the `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Which row in the file is the problem one? The Jet provider [guesses the correct data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx) by reading the first 8 rows of the file (by default), so if the 9th row is a string then you might see this problem. Although I'm not sure why you're using this approach rather than [`BULK INSERT` or `OPENROWSET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx).

Comment: I load it into a datatable so that I can then scan through the rows to get rid if invalid records.  Its a CSV that is saved from Excel, so there are several thousand records that are null.  Once its cleaned up, I bulk insert it.  The problem row is several hundred down, so your suggestion makes sense.  Is there a way to force the data type?

Comment: I'll do something with the InvalidException once i've got the logic worked out and have an idea what could go wrong.  At this point I just want to get it working correctly.

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to? See the section headed "Missing values", it explains how to use `IMEX=1`.

Comment: I looked at that, but doesn't make a difference for .csv files. I found a link to using a schema.ini file to specify the columns, so am writing a method to write the .ini out for each file type.  Hopefully that works

Comment: Always feels good to work out your own problem, the schema.ini file did the trick: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Kerberos42 That's good, you might want to answer your own question to help others who may have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue. Thanks to Pondlife for getting me pointed in the right direction.  I figured it had something to do with data types, just not sure where it was getting walloped.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: FYI, link-only answers are [not considered ideal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer) on SO, because links break and there is no context. Editing your answer to give a brief explanation of what you did would be good.